# set file attributes for is_uploaded_file true

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm developing Java Web Server supporting php via php-cgi call in java
now, is_uploaded_file is always false,
how to set java uploaded post files with my server to be valid for move_uploaded_file function?
may be I may contact somehow developers of PHP language?
why only apache can?

Comment: I think `is_uploaded_file()` just checks if the file is in `upload_tmp_dir` folder. So you just need to have your server store the file into that directory.

Comment: I use php function sys_get_temp_dir() for getting tmp uploads dir where I put the uploaded file, also I set +rw rights for the uploaded file and set owner and group to www-data. nothing helps

Comment: As far as I can tell from [the source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/e2d05bfcb2b788932bacf53bcd4cab8ec27a8dd4/main/SAPI.h#L112), there’s a private super global that is set during the request processing that `is_uploaded_file` [checks](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/296f76453c075d9899044e4a4f74a608dcd6cc6b/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L2431) and for security reasons, this is not accessible to user land code.

Comment: They're not the same settings. Uploads use the ini.php setting `upload_tmp_dir`, `sys_get_tmp_dir()` uses the `sys_temp_dir` setting.

Comment: thank you guys,
I read that php-fpm is more secure than usage of php-cgi for this case
so I moved forward with php-fpm and it is already fine.

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys, I read that php-fpm is more secure than usage of php-cgi for this case so I moved forward with php-fpm and it is already fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).